# What is the best approach from Object Modelling to code generation for Web services server and client side entities?

Tags: web-services, rest, uml

I want to create an Object Model (may be in **UML?**) and then use some tools to generate entities in **JAVA** (for client side) and in **PHP** (for server side).

Primarily, I wish to write a JAVA client side application communicating with a PHP based web services using **REST** and **JSON.**

Idea is to avoid writing (and then maintaining), object entities separately in java and php.

JSON serialization of entities would be a big plus

Please suggest tools/approach that I could take to achieve the objective.

Comment: I have been able to use Eclipse EMF UML2 plugin to generate java code from UML, but what do I do for generating PHP classes ? Any, suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

**you need to implement the Apache solr server**

[Solr client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/ExampleUsage)

[Ibm developer works on Solr](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/)

[Check php manual about the service](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php)

[Wiki solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP)

Comment: Sam, Thank you for the answer. But I am looking for an approach or tool(s) to convert Modelling language (like UML) to generating PHP and JAVA classes. Does Solr fulfill that need ?